# Login page on MySQL site not redirecting upon login

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

First, big thanks to @NBK for pointing out my password_verify issue.
I read through both of the recommended articles they provided,
How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords (7 answers)
Reference - What does this error mean in PHP? (36 answers)

Alas I'm still having problems with the login form at trinasgame.joshuasplace2018.com/game/login.php wherein once you login you're supposed to be redirected to a super-simple index.php page that should say Hi, [nickname]. Welcome to the site!  However, at this time if you try to login the page just kicks your information out.

I was initially confident the issue to be related to syntax, but I continue to struggle to figure out exactly what is wrong.  Error logging is enabled, but not seeing any errors get generated, pulled code from https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php using steps1+2 of creating the login form.
The login page code is as follows

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require 'dbt.php';
    
    
    // Check if the nick is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
    if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
        header("location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
    
    // Define variables and initialize with empty values
    $nickname = $password = "";
    $nickname_err = $password_err = "";
     
    // Processing form data when form is submitted
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
     
        // Check if nickname is empty
        if(empty(trim($_POST["nickname"]))){
            $nickname_err = "Please enter nickname.";
        } else{
            $nickname = trim($_POST["nickname"]);
        }
        
         // Check if password is empty
        if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
            $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
        } else{
            $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
        }
        
            // Validate credentials
    if(empty($nickname_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE nickname = ?";
        
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_nickname);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_nickname = $nickname;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                
                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $nickname, $password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, BCRYPT)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();
                            
                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["nickname"] = $nickname;                            
                            
                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: index.php");
                            exit();
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
<html>
   
   <head>
      <title>Login Page</title>
      
      <style type = "text/css">
         body {
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size:14px;
         }
         label {
            font-weight:bold;
            width:100px;
            font-size:14px;
         }
         .box {
            border:#666666 solid 1px;
         }
      </style>
      
   </head>
   
   <body bgcolor = "#FFFFFF">
    
      <div align = "center">
         <div style = "width:300px; border: solid 1px #333333; " align = "left">
            <div style = "background-color:#333333; color:#FFFFFF; padding:3px;"><b>Login</b></div>
                
            <div style = "margin:30px">
               
               <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">                                            
                                              <div class="container">
                                                <label for="nickname"><b>Nickname</b></label>
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="Nickname" name="nickname" required>

                                                <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
                                                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>

                                                <button type="submit">Login</button>
                                                <label>
                                                  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
                                                </label>
                                              </div>

                                              <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
                                                New here? <a href="register.php">Register!</a>
                                                <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
                                                <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
                                              </div>
                                        </form>
               
               <div style = "font-size:11px; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
                    
            </div>
                
         </div>
            
      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

The index page

```
    require 'dbt.php';
    session_start();
    
    // Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
    if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
        header("location: login.php");
        exit;
    }
?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="us-ascii"><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <style type="text/css">p {
                            font-size: 15px;
                        }
                        p#login {
                            border: 1px black;                          
                        }
            </style>
            <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" rel="stylesheet" />
            <title>Trina&#39;s G-o-R | Dev mode</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h2>Index/Game home page</h2>
                        
                        <p>Hi, <b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["nickname"]); ?></b>. Welcome to the site! </p>
                        <br/>
                            <!-- button onclick="rndInt()">Roll Dice</button>
                            <br/>
                            <div>
                                <p class="label">Latest roll:&nbsp; &nbsp;<span id="last_roll"></span></p>
                            </div-->
                            
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2><a href = "logout.php">Sign Out</a></h2>
        </body>     
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't know what "just kicks your information out" means. It looks like 7 nested if statements to reach the redirect and there is no instrumentation of your code. That makes it very difficult to understand the flow and debug. Restructure and decompose the functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `exit()` when you redirect:

```
// Redirect user to welcome page
header("location: index.php");
exit();
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @Mike67, but unfortunately I'm still experiencing the same issue.  I've added your suggestion to my question, and I will continue researching the issue.

Comment: that did work, but what i found was a new hurdle ;P  So, now the redirect works, but I'm having trouble getting the nickname variable to come thru; since that's not the issue I reported I'm marking this one answered.  Thanks, again for the help!